# Wrong element position only for safari

Tags: html, css, safari, position

I have prepared an html file to show you the problem:
http://eyenet.it/problema_safari.html

I tried on Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Opera ... buttons "aggiungi al carrello" and "mostra i dettagli", they are displayed correctly where I want:
http://eyenet.it/posizione_desiderata.png

But if i try on Safari, positioning is wrong:
http://eyenet.it/posizione_sbagliata.png

Can anyone help me to fix it on Safari?

Thank you all!

Regards,
Renato

Comment: Please put the code directly into your question.

Comment: And please give us a minimal reproducible example,  your code has dozens of CSS property settings (color) which are not relevant to this problem and which make it very hard to see what is going on. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also, please tell us which OS you are running Safari on.

Answer (score 0):

i solved using "bottom: -300px" instead "bottom: 70%".
It works for all browsers.
Thank you all.